# Call another .bat file from within the same folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, load

I have my primary Batch file in a folder with a second batch file in the same folder. How do I make it so that the second batch file can be called from within the first. This must be able to work with any user's Windows computer.

I figured it was something like this (in the primary file):

```
call C:\%UserProfile%\#Hashtag\gameData\second.bat
```

But it says my syntax or path is incorrect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
call "%~dp0second.bat"
```

`%~dp0` gives you the path (including a trailing backslash) of the location of your currently running batchfile.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing violently with @Stephan, there's a sort of invisible change to the code besides using the `%~dp0`, in that the path now is also in `"` double quotes.  That's most likely the issue with the first one because of expansion of the `%UserProfile%` variable... my guess is there's a space in that string.

There's no issue using the `#` character in a filename.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to the folder name #hashtag it is throwing an error. Add the folder path to PATH variable and then try calling the batch file name directly.